# How to Combine To Queries With MongoDB Operators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have these two search expressions. I was wandering how I could combine these two into one expression using maybe `$or` or `$and` operators using Mongoose.

Here is the code:

```
const mailContent = await Mail.find({ sender: id, receivers: { $elemMatch: { $eq: req.user._id } } }).populate('sender');
const outMailContent = await Mail.find({ sender: req.user._id, receivers: { $elemMatch: { $eq: id } }, type: {$not:{$eq: 'offer'}} }).populate('sender');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `$or`

```
const mailContent = await Mail.find(
  { $or:[
    { sender: id, receivers: { $elemMatch: { $eq: req.user._id } } },
    { sender: req.user._id, receivers: { $elemMatch: { $eq: id } }, type: {$not:{$eq: 'offer'}} }
  ] }
).populate('sender');
```